# Android - Retrieving in item from a Room database by its ID

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to retrieve a single Client item from my Room database. Every client is displayed in a list, and each client has an edit button on them. When the button is pressed, I would like to retrieve that client from the database by their id. Their details will then be displayed on an edit screen.

My problem arises in actually getting the client from the database. So far I have tried 2 approaches:

#### Coroutines based approach

I have tried to retrieve the item using coroutine based functions with Room. This approach does "work" to an extent, but in its current form the coroutine ends up retrieving the newly searched for client ***after*** the edit screen has been displayed. This makes it so that when you edit a client, you end up editing the one you tried to edit previously.

I have tried to counteract this by using .join(), using `viewModelScope.async` rather than `launch` and then attempting to use `.await`, and a few other ideas, but none of them have worked.

**ClientDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface ClientDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tblClient WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getClientToEdit(id: Int): List<Client>
}
```

**ClientRepository.kt**

```
class ClientRepository(private val clientDao: ClientDao) {

    val clientSearchResults = MutableLiveData<List<Client>>() 

    suspend fun getClientToEdit(id: Int) {
        clientSearchResults.value = clientDao.getClientToEdit(id)
    }
}
```

**ClientViewModel.kt**

```
class ClientViewModel(application: Application): ViewModel() {

    private val repository: ClientRepository
    val clientSearchResults: MutableLiveData<List<Client>>

    init {
        val clientDB = ManagementDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val clientDao = clientDB.clientDao()
        repository = ClientRepository(clientDao)

        clientSearchResults = repository.clientSearchResults
    }

    fun getClientToEdit(clientId: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getClientToEdit(clientId)
    }

}
```

**ManagementApp.kt**

```
ClientScreen(
   onEditClient = { id ->
       clientViewModel.getClientToEdit(id)
           val editClientList: List<Client>? = clientViewModel.clientSearchResults.value
           //This looks awful but it works
           // It just gets the client details of the selected client
           if (editClientList != null) {
                if (editClientList.firstOrNull() != null) {
                     selectedClient = editClientList[0]
```

If I could just find a way to make it so that `clientViewModel.getClientToEdit(id)` fully executed before running the rest of the code in ManagementApp.kt, it would work. The problem is I'm not sure how.

#### Flow based approach:

I didn't really think this approach would work, but it was worth a shot. I have tried to retrieve the item using a flow list, in the same way I have been retrieving the whole list.

**ClientDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface ClientDao {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM tblClient WHERE id = :id")
   fun getClientToEdit(id: Int): Flow<List<Client>>
}
```

**ClientRepository.kt**

```
class ClientRepository(private val clientDao: ClientDao) {
    fun getClientSearchResults(id: Int): Flow<List<Client>> =
        clientDao.getClientToEdit(id)
}
```

**ClientViewModel.kt**

```
class ClientViewModel(application: Application): ViewModel() {
        private val repository: ClientRepository
    
        init {
            val clientDB = ManagementDatabase.getDatabase(application)
            val clientDao = clientDB.clientDao()
            repository = ClientRepository(clientDao)
        }
    
        fun getClientToEdit(clientId: Int): LiveData<List<Client>> {
            return repository.getClientSearchResults(id = clientId).asLiveData()
        }
    }
```

**ManagementApp.kt**

```
ClientScreen(
    onEditClient = { id ->
        val editClientList by clientViewModel.getClientToEdit(id).observeAsState(listOf())
        //This looks awful but it works
        // It just gets the client details of the selected client
        if (editClientList != null) {
             if (editClientList.firstOrNull() != null) {
                  selectedClient = editClientList[0]
```

The problem with this approach is that .observeAsState gives me the '@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function' error (Although the snippet of code above is actually within a @Composable function).

If anyone could provide some much needed help I would greatly appreciate it. I'm new to Android and have struggled with Room quite a bit, so my apologies if the code isn't really up to scratch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the button is pressed, I would like to retrieve that client from the database by their id. Their details will then be displayed on an edit screen.

If by "edit screen" you mean proper screen with ViewModel to which you navigate using for example androidx.navigation, better approach would be to just pass the `id` to that new screen and do the loading in its ViewModel.

> If I could just find a way to make it so that `clientViewModel.getClientToEdit(id)` fully executed before running the rest of the code in ManagementApp.kt

You can do that by making `getClientToEdit` suspend fun and then doing something like this:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
ClientScreen(
    onEditClient = { id ->
        scope.launch {
            clientViewModel.getClientToEdit(id)
            // now getClientToEdit was executed
        }
    }
)
```

I would also suggest returning `Client` directly from the `getClientToEdit`, using LiveData for that is not necessary

> Although the snippet of code above is actually within a @Composable function

It's not, you are trying to call it from `onClick` callback and `onClick` is not marked with `@Composable`, so you cannot call composable functions from there.

---

To sum it up:
If the result of your action is navigation to another screen, you can do one of these:

1. Pass just the id to that other screen and do the loading there, as I suggested.
2. Launch coroutine inside `onEditClient` callback, load the client and navigate from there as shown above.
3. Load the client in ViewModel, update some state there and navigate based on that state, something like:

```
// ViewModel
val actions = MutableSharedFlow<Action>()
fun editClient(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val client = repository.getClientToEdit(clientId)
    actions.emit(NavigateToEditScreen(client))
}

// Screen
val action by clientViewModel.actions.collectAsState()
LaunchedEffect(action) {
    if (action is NavigateToEditScreen) {
        // do the navigation using action.client
    }
}
ClientScreen(
   onEditClient = { id ->
       clientViewModel.editClient(id)
   }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I passed the viewModel to the editing screen and got the client from there and it is now working, albeit with a little delay where it shows the previously edited client for about a second before showing the client that was actually selected for editing. One question: how would you go about returning the client directly from the `getClientToEdit()` function? Currently I am launching the function with viewModelScope, but I don't know how to return a value from a coroutine like that.

Comment: Nevermind, by changing the code in my ViewModel to this:
`@WorkerThread
    fun getClientToEdit(clientId: Int): List<Client>? = runBlocking {
        repository.getClientToEdit(clientId)
    }`
I managed to get it to work perfectly! Thanks again.

Comment: That's not a proper coroutine solution though, `suspend fun getClientToEdit(clientId: Int): List<Client>? = repository.getClientToEdit(clientId)` is better

Comment: Also "with a little delay where it shows the previously edited client for about a second" - that sounds wrong - you should create *new* screen and *new* viewmodel for every editation, there shouldn't be a way to get the previous one in your viewmodel

Comment: Yes, I know its not a particularly good solution, but I was just trying to get it to at least work for now. So in your second comment are you saying that I should be creating a new Screen object every time the edit client button is pressed? As opposed to navigating to a previously defined screen object and passing the clientViewModel and clientId?